# Sum cells after the first non zero value found - Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, conditional-statements

I would like to know how to sum only 4 cells after the cell is not equal to zero.

Here are some case scenarios:

```
0 3 0 5 7 8 6 0 0 0 0 -> Result 3 + 0 + 5 + 7

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 -> Result 1 + 2 +`0 + 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 0 -> Result 1 + 2 + 1 + 1

0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 0 -> Result 1 + 0 + 0 + 0
```

I would like to sum the 4 cells starting from the one (starting from the left) which doesnt have any 0.

I guess I have to do something like `=SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:H1,1,SMALL(IF(A1:H1,COLUMN(A:H)),4)))` but this formula will exclude 0 value cells found after the first non-zero cell.

Could you give me some guidance please?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work (slightly longer than the first answer, though)

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(1:1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(1:1<>0,),0)))),0,0,1,4))
```

Values should be anywhere in `row 1`.

Comment: @pnuts Right. It seems to work that way unless I missed something.

Comment: Hi @Pnuts! Thanks a lot for your help! Do you think it possible to have the same in range A1:H1 better than from A1:A6 ? (in row instead of column order)?

Comment: @Londonuser You're very welcome! If my answer worked would you mark it as correct and/or upvote it, please. Thanks!